# Fade In UIButton - Beginner

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to display a button, and the button should fade In and show. The following code will just show an instant button but not fade In and display. How can i get this done ?

```
  [button setFrame:CGRectMake(183,95,34.0f,39.0f)];

  [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                        delay:1.0
                      options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                   animations:^{button.alpha = 1.0;}
                   completion:nil];

  [self.view addSubview: button];
```

Comment: before animations starts, is your button.alpha = 0?

Comment: also move the animation after `[self.view addsubview: button]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(183,95,34.0f,39.0f)];
button.alpha=0.0;
 [self.view addSubview: button]; 
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                    delay:1.0
                  options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
               animations:^{button.alpha = 1.0;}
               completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this once, try this, options should be like this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse| UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                     animations:^{
                         button.alpha = 1.0f;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         // Do nothing
                     }];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[self.view addSubview:button];
button.alpha=0.0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                      delay:0.7
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{button.alpha = 1.0;}
                 completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You must add the button in view before you animate. Otherwise no animation will occur. (You are adding the animation code first then adding the button to view hierarchy)
2. First Make alpha value to your initial alpha value.
3. Then animate the button, with custom animation.
4. In order to see the animation completely, you shouldn't perform animation in view did load method.

   ```
       [self.view addSubview: button];

       // Set the alpha first to hide itself
       button.alpha = 0.0;

       [button setFrame:CGRectMake(183,95,34.0f,39.0f)];

       // Perform animation In view did appear or desired place except view did load
       [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                             delay:1.0
                           options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                        animations:^{

                            button.alpha = 1.0;

                        }
                        completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                            NSLog(@"Animation completed");

                        }];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

try these..

```
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(183,95,34.0f,39.0f)];
```

> button.alpha=0.0; //put its alpha value 0.

```
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

change buttons alpha value in animateWithDuration..

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                delay:1.0
              options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
           animations:^{
                   button.alpha = 1.0;//here make its alpha value 1..
                       }
           completion:nil];
```

i hope it helps...